# Oracle SQL Joining on Null Value

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I'm a bit of an sql nublet so hopefully you can bear with me.

I have 2 tables which I am performing a Left Outer Join On (Calendar and Employees).

The first Table is a list of dates between 2005 and 2030 and the second table is a list of employee clockings.

I need to create an output using both tables to show when employees did or did not clock in for a specified week.

This is the code I'm using below:

```
select cal.account_date,
cal.day_value,
Emp_Clock.emp_no,
Emp_Clock.Basic,
Emp_Clock.MWOT,
Emp_Clock.WEOT,
Emp_Clock.Clean
from

(Select work_day as account_date, 
Work_Time_Calendar_API.Get_Week_Day(WORK_DAY) as Day_Value from Calendar
where
Calendar_ID = '24/7'
and
work_day between 
          to_date(CALENDAR_API.Get_First_Week_Day ('2017', '&WEEK_NO', '6' )) 
      AND to_date(CALENDAR_API.Get_First_Week_Day ('2017', '&WEEK_NO', '6' ))+6) Cal

Left Outer Join

(select company_id,emp_no , account_date,
round(max(decode(wage_code,'MWOT',wage_hours)),2) as MWOT, 
round(max(decode(wage_code,'BASIC',wage_hours)),2) as BASIC,
round(max(decode(wage_code,'WEOT',wage_hours)),2) as WEOT,
round(max(decode(wage_code,'CLEAN',wage_hours)),2) as CLEAN,
ifsapp.Work_Time_Calendar_API.Get_Week_Day(account_date) as Day_Value
from Employees where company_ID = 'Redacted'  
group by emp_no, account_date,company_ID
order by emp_no) Emp_Clock

on cal.account_date = emp_clock.account_date

order by emp_clock.emp_no, cal.account_date
```

Currently the table only pulls back the dates on which an employee has worked(current_result.jpg) and I assume this is because I'm joining on the date(The only field I can join on).

Is there any possible way I can rework this query to pull back the result I'm after (Desired_Result.jpg) or is there not enough information within both tables to do a join this way.

Current result:

[image: Current Result]

Expected result:

[image: Desired Result]

Edit: Attachment of Subquery Result

[Subquery Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMQnq.jpg)

Edit 2:

Result of Subquery 1:

```
Account_Date               Day_Value
7/1/2017   00:00:00         Saturday
8/1/2017   00:00:00         Sunday
9/1/2017   00:00:00         Monday
10/1/2017  00:00:00         Tuesday
11/1/2017  00:00:00         Wednesday
```

etc

Result of Subquery 2:

```
Company_ID  Emp_No  account_date  MWOT  BASIC    WEOT    CLEAN  Day_VALUE
 Redacted     1       9/1/2017    null    8      null     null   Monday
 Redacted     1      10/1/2017    null    8      null     null   Tuesday
 Redacted     1      11/1/2017    null    8      null     null   Wednesday
 Redacted     2       7/1/2017    null   null      8      null   Saturday
 Redacted     2       9/1/2017    null    8      null     null   Monday
 Redacted     2      10/1/2017    null    8      null     null   Tuesday
 Redacted     3       9/1/2017     2     9.25    null     null   Monday
 Redacted     3      10/1/2017     2     9.25    null     null   Tuesday
 Redacted     3      11/1/2017     2     9.25    null     null  Wednesday
```

etc

Comment: If run by itself: Does the first subquery on table "calendar" produce all required dates? (*The left join should allow all the dates to be listed.*)

Comment: Yes I've added the output of the subquery to the main body.

Comment: I'm sorry, just noticed you have an `order by` in the second subquery. get rid of that and try it again. Aside from that I can't see anything that would stop the expected result.

Comment: I've removed the order by in the second sub-query as suggested but it still pulls back the same result. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: provide some sample data (**as text, not images**) from the first subquery, and the second subquery (separately)  **LEFT JOIN allows NULLs** you can omit names etc. from the sample data. it's just a sample we want, not an overload

Comment: Hopefully that's what your after

Comment: Yes. Believe I  see the issue now. You need a list of emp_no with nothing else. Eg It might come from an employee table. Call it e. Now cross join e to cal. Now left join subquery 2 to dates as you have it plus emp_no to e.emp_no.  The cross join gives all emp_no for all dates.

Comment: I only have a phone to eork on right now so not able to write the sql example.

Comment: Awesome I'll give it a go thanks for all your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing query lacks a list of all employee numbers (that you need for that query) and that list should be "cross joined" to the dates to produce all combinations of date/emp_no. Once that Cartesian product exists, then left join date to date, and emp_no to emp_no, to output all the rows even when there are gaps in the clicked hours.

See this working demo at: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83a461/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBQRY1
    (ACCOUNT_DATE TIMESTAMP, DAY_VALUE VARCHAR2(9))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO SUBQRY1 (Account_Date, Day_Value)
         VALUES ('01-Jul-2017 12:00:00 AM', 'Saturday')
    INTO SUBQRY1 (Account_Date, Day_Value)
         VALUES ('01-Aug-2017 12:00:00 AM', 'Sunday')
    INTO SUBQRY1 (Account_Date, Day_Value)
         VALUES ('01-Sep-2017 12:00:00 AM', 'Monday')
    INTO SUBQRY1 (Account_Date, Day_Value)
         VALUES ('01-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', 'Tuesday')
    INTO SUBQRY1 (Account_Date, Day_Value)
         VALUES ('01-Nov-2017 12:00:00 AM', 'Wednesday')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE SUBQRY2
    (COMPANY_ID VARCHAR2(8), EMP_NO INT, ACCOUNT_DATE TIMESTAMP, MWOT VARCHAR2(4), BASIC VARCHAR2(4), WEOT VARCHAR2(4), CLEAN VARCHAR2(4), DAY_VALUE VARCHAR2(9))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 1, '01-Sep-2017 12:00:00 AM', NULL, '8', NULL, NULL, 'Monday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 1, '01-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', NULL, '8', NULL, NULL, 'Tuesday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 1, '01-Nov-2017 12:00:00 AM', NULL, '8', NULL, NULL, 'Wednesday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 2, '01-Jul-2017 12:00:00 AM', NULL, NULL, '8', NULL, 'Saturday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 2, '01-Sep-2017 12:00:00 AM', NULL, '8', NULL, NULL, 'Monday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 2, '01-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', NULL, '8', NULL, NULL, 'Tuesday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 3, '01-Sep-2017 12:00:00 AM', '2', '9.25', NULL, NULL, 'Monday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 3, '01-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', '2', '9.25', NULL, NULL, 'Tuesday')
    INTO SUBQRY2 (Company_ID, Emp_No, account_date, MWOT, BASIC, WEOT, CLEAN, Day_VALUE)
         VALUES ('Redacted', 3, '01-Nov-2017 12:00:00 AM', '2', '9.25', NULL, NULL, 'Wednesday')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with subqry3 as (
  /* this is just an example, you don't have to do it this way */
  select distinct Emp_No from subqry2
  )

select
*
from subqry1 d /* d = dates */
cross join subqry3 e /* e = employess */
left join subqry2 h  /* h = hours */
    on d.Account_Date = h.Account_Date
   and e.emp_no = h.emp_no
order by e.emp_no, d.Account_Date
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83a461/2/0)**:

```
|          ACCOUNT_DATE | DAY_VALUE | EMP_NO | COMPANY_ID | EMP_NO |          ACCOUNT_DATE |   MWOT |  BASIC |   WEOT |  CLEAN | DAY_VALUE |
|-----------------------|-----------|--------|------------|--------|-----------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|-----------|
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.0 |  Saturday |      1 |     (null) | (null) |                (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
| 2017-08-01 00:00:00.0 |    Sunday |      1 |     (null) | (null) |                (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
| 2017-09-01 00:00:00.0 |    Monday |      1 |   Redacted |      1 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00.0 | (null) |      8 | (null) | (null) |    Monday |
| 2017-10-01 00:00:00.0 |   Tuesday |      1 |   Redacted |      1 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00.0 | (null) |      8 | (null) | (null) |   Tuesday |
| 2017-11-01 00:00:00.0 | Wednesday |      1 |   Redacted |      1 | 2017-11-01 00:00:00.0 | (null) |      8 | (null) | (null) | Wednesday |
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.0 |  Saturday |      2 |   Redacted |      2 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.0 | (null) | (null) |      8 | (null) |  Saturday |
| 2017-08-01 00:00:00.0 |    Sunday |      2 |     (null) | (null) |                (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
| 2017-09-01 00:00:00.0 |    Monday |      2 |   Redacted |      2 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00.0 | (null) |      8 | (null) | (null) |    Monday |
| 2017-10-01 00:00:00.0 |   Tuesday |      2 |   Redacted |      2 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00.0 | (null) |      8 | (null) | (null) |   Tuesday |
| 2017-11-01 00:00:00.0 | Wednesday |      2 |     (null) | (null) |                (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.0 |  Saturday |      3 |     (null) | (null) |                (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
| 2017-08-01 00:00:00.0 |    Sunday |      3 |     (null) | (null) |                (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
| 2017-09-01 00:00:00.0 |    Monday |      3 |   Redacted |      3 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00.0 |      2 |   9.25 | (null) | (null) |    Monday |
| 2017-10-01 00:00:00.0 |   Tuesday |      3 |   Redacted |      3 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00.0 |      2 |   9.25 | (null) | (null) |   Tuesday |
| 2017-11-01 00:00:00.0 | Wednesday |      3 |   Redacted |      3 | 2017-11-01 00:00:00.0 |      2 |   9.25 | (null) | (null) | Wednesday |
```

Comment: Thanks for all the Help. This indeed solved the issue :D